# Unable to Validate XML for KVM/QEMU Snapshot in 20.10

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

When trying to take a KVM snapshot using `virsh snapshot-create-as --domain vm --name vm-snap --disk-only --diskspec "sdc,snapshot=internal,file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/vm.qcow2,,new"`, I get the error:

```
error: XML document failed to validate against schema: 
 Unable to validate doc against /usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domainsnapshot.rng  
Extra element disks in interleave  
Element domainsnapshot failed to validate content
```

Yet the XML is validating fine using `visrh edit vm.xml` but something isn't validating here.

- OS: Ubuntu 20.10
- qemu: 1:5.0-5ubuntu9.1
- libvirt: 6.6.0-1ubuntu3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: The XML can be looked at via --print-xml

```
$ virsh snapshot-create-as --domain h-test --name h-test-snap --diskspec "vda,snapshot=internal,file=/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images/h-test.qcow.snapshot" --print-xml
<domainsnapshot>
  <name>h-test-snap</name>
  <disks>
    <disk name='vda' snapshot='internal'>
      <source file='/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images/h-test.qcow.snapshot'/>
    </disk>
  </disks>
</domainsnapshot>
```

### Comparing other releases

- Hirsute + Focal + Bionic => same generated XML
- Hirsute + Focal => same verification error
- Bionic => reports "unsupported configuration"

The problem is that "internal" would mean to use the same file on disk, which
is mutually exclusive with doing a snapshot including VM state.

Looking through some old usage I had seen the following slight modification
worked for me:

```
$ virsh snapshot-create-as --domain h-test --name h-test-snap --disk-only --diskspec vda,file=/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images/h-test.qcow.snapshot
```

Your case did not specify `--disk-only` which means you want to save guest memory
state as well. But that can not be done in `internal` mode.

Note: I'd usually also add `--atomic --quiesce`

If we compare the XML of my suggested working command it does no more have the snapshot=internal.

```
<domainsnapshot>
  <name>h-test-snap</name>
  <disks>
    <disk name='vda'>
      <source file='/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images/h-test.qcow.snapshot'/>
    </disk>
  </disks>
</domainsnapshot>
```

So to fix your issue either switch to external+disk-only mode (as suggested above) or if you really want to save mem-state AND disks, but at the same time need to control the files (still mutually exclusive with internal mode I think, but not sure) you can use `--memspec` to let it know where to put this data.

That would be something like:

```
$ virsh snapshot-create-as --domain h-test2 --name h-test-snap --diskspec vda,snapshot=external,file=/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images/h-test2.qcow.snapshot --memspec snapshot=external,file=/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images/h-test2.mem --print-xml
<domainsnapshot>
  <name>h-test-snap</name>
  <memory snapshot='external' file='/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images/h-test2.mem'/>
  <disks>
    <disk name='vda' snapshot='external'>
      <source file='/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images/h-test2.qcow.snapshot'/>
    </disk>
  </disks>
</domainsnapshot>
```

Note: the latter is still so uncommon that it has no full apparmor support yet,
and thereby misses to add rules for it in time. I filed [bug 1905674](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1905674) for it.
In that case you'd need to add an override either for all guests (`/etc/apparmor.d/local/abstractions/libvirt-qemu`) or an individual guest (`/etc/apparmor.d/libvirt/libvirt-<uuid>`)

> Note: BTW to allow for more modification/experiments - you can check the XML without triggering an actual snapshot, example:

```
$ virt-xml-validate snap.xml domainsnapshot
Relax-NG validity error : Extra element disks in interleave
snap.xml:3: element disks: Relax-NG validity error : Element domainsnapshot failed to validate content
snap.xml fails to validate
```

> Note: please do mind that if your guest has multiple disks and you
> want to manually add diskspec, then you need to add it explicitly for
> all disks. Otherwise the apparmor rules can not be created and it will
> fail with: "Permission denied"

> Note: if you want to exclude some disks from the backup the man page
> explains: "To exclude a disk from an external snapshot use --diskspec
> ,snapshot=no." (not sure about passthrough disks in that context)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it's a little more complex than that. I tried most of those options. I've updated the question to show --disk-only which I also tried. The issue with doing snapshot=external is that it then tries to snapshot the passthrough disks I have added even though I'm specifying sdc and it gives the error that it can't snapshot sdd, which is why I ended up with the command as I did. How does one go about excluding a disk for snapshot?

Comment: Hi, IIRC you have to pass --diskspec for ALL of the disks and the ones you want to exclude get something like ... "--diskspec vdd,snapshot=no". But TBH I've used it for secondary disks that I didn't want to back-up, but not yet for passthrough disks.

Comment: @BettyVonSchmartenhausen - I've added excluding to the answer (as a Note) for completeness, but as I'm unsure if/how that works for passthrough disks please let me know after you tried.

Comment: I have passed ALL of the disks and this has worked great, thanks! As a further note/question for completeness; I realise I can't delete external snapshots in the usual way... "virsh snapshot-delete" so have used "virsh blockcommit vm-name sdc --verbose --pivot --active" to merge the snapshot and then have deleted the snapshot once merged. How do I tell libvirt that this is now removed? When I try and create a new snapshot with the same name I get the error "operation failed: domain moment snapshot-name already exists" -- BVS

Comment: Managed to remove the snapshot metadata with "virsh snapshot-delete vm-name --metadata --current" -- BVS

Comment: Glad I could help, could you convert your overall new process into an ask-ubuntu answer here to help other users?